# How to pass context result as argurment for another function in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, youtube-dl

I have my django app which searches youtube and return result as a dictionary which i render them in  template, one of the returned value is link , now I have a download button they way i wish it to function is whenever you click a button it should take the url for the clicked result and pass it to another download function as an argument. How do I accomplish that ?

Here is my view.py

```
def index(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    query = request.POST['video_name']
    n = 12
    search = SearchVideos(str(query), offset = 1, mode = "json", max_results = n)

    ytresults = search.result()

    result_dict = json.loads(ytresults)        

    context = {
        "result" : result_dict,
    
            
    }
    template_name = "youloader/results.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context)

else:
    query = "no copyright sound"
    n = 12

    search = SearchVideos(str(query), offset = 1, mode = "json", max_results = n)

    index_results = search.result()

    result_dict = json.loads(index_results)

    context = {
        "result" : result_dict
    }

    template_name = "youloader/index.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context)

    

def downloading_video(request):
   try:
   with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(video_opts) as ydl:
       ydl.download(link)

except:
   pass
```

here are my template.html

```
<div class="my-4" >
<div style="padding-top: 20px">
<div class="row" >
{%  for result in result.search_result %}
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="card shadow-sm border-0 my-2">
<img src="{{ result.thumbnails.1 }}" alt="{{ result.channelId }}">

<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ result.link }}</h5>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between card-subtitle my-2 text-muted small">
        

        <a href="{{ result.link }}" class="text-secondary font-weight-bold">
            <i class="fa fa-tablet mr-1"></i>{{ result.channel }}
        </a>

        <span><i class="fa fa-stopwatch mr-1"></i>{{ result.duration }}</span>

        <span><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1"></i>{{ result.views }}</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Download</button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Audio</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Video</a>
        </div>

        <br>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the sample of the template rendered.

[image: result page]

Comment: you want to export a link from index function to downloading_video function?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want. @RezaGH

Comment: Define a URL to initiated download by calling downloading_video(). POST download link to it when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

in the index function you can use redirect instead of render

index function:

```
def index(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    .
    .
    .
    result_dict = json.loads(index_results)
    link = result_dict.link
    return redirect('youtubedl:download', link ) # first arg is your url route to downloading_video function like 'appname:urlname' and second is the link that coming from result_dic


else:
    .
    .
```

downloading_video function:

```
def downloading_video(request, link):
    try:
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(video_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(link)

    except:
       pass
```

this is the way i think you should use because your download function is in a separate template

Comment: if i return redirect i wouldn't get the preview i want for the user to select based on the results. I want it to work like youtube but instead of playing the video, the button downloads it

Comment: can you explain more. when and where do you want to display download button and explain when and where you wish your user start download?

Comment: I attached the screenshot showing where the button is already is after the search result has been presented to the user, then he/she will select the video to download

Comment: these results is getting from youtube without saving in the database? in other word there are just displaying?

Comment: yes no database involved they are just returned from the view

Comment: let me think about it. i'll let you know

Comment: ok, you can even pull from github it will be a huge help [Github Link](https://github.com/JAXPARROW/DjTube)

Comment: in this case that you don't have database involved, you should render searched results in one page. then build a detail page for the item that user clicked. finally in the detail page use above code (redirect with the link i mean)

Comment: share your telegram id